# RoR - rake rs:index fails with NameError on Rails 4.0.4(4.1.7), thinking sphinx 3.1.1

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, thinking-sphinx

I tried to index my mysql database for sphinx search engine and that's what I get. I went through the whole entire stackoverflow, downgraded my rails, updated sphinx and ts like 5 or 6 times. I double checked my code(maybe problem's over there). I depreciated config.threadsafe! and whatever else and it still doesn't work at all. Probably you could help me out. Here are console logs and parts of the original code:

```
pchudinov:xxx chud$ rake ts:index
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:222: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
DEPRECATION WARNING: config.threadsafe! is deprecated. Rails applications behave by default as thread safe in production as long as config.cache_classes and config.eager_load are set to true. (called from <class:Application> at /xxx/config/application.rb:29)
searchd is not currently running.
Stopped searchd daemon (pid: ).
Generating configuration to /xxx/config/development.sphinx.conf
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant RealTeams
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `const_get'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:226:in `block in constantize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `inject'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:224:in `constantize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/string/inflections.rb:66:in `constantize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/core/index.rb:43:in `model'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/index.rb:9:in `append_source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/interpreter.rb:63:in `__source'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/interpreter.rb:20:in `indexes'
/xxx/app/indices/real_teams_index.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/core/interpreter.rb:3:in `translate!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/core/index.rb:39:in `interpret_definition!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/active_record/index.rb:32:in `sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration/consistent_ids.rb:31:in `collect'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration/consistent_ids.rb:31:in `sources'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration/consistent_ids.rb:19:in `attributes'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration/consistent_ids.rb:23:in `sphinx_internal_ids'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration/consistent_ids.rb:7:in `reconcile'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:87:in `render'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:96:in `block in render_to_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:96:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/configuration.rb:96:in `render_to_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:13:in `configure'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/rake_interface.rb:24:in `index'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/thinking-sphinx-3.1.1/lib/thinking_sphinx/tasks.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => ts:index
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Here is the original code for "RealTeam":

controller:

```
  def search
      @real_teams = RealTeam.search params[:search]
  end
```

model:

```
class RealTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :players
  has_many :home_matches, :class_name => 'Match', :foreign_key => 'team_home_id'
  has_many :away_matches, :class_name => 'Match', :foreign_key => 'team_away_id'
  has_many :performances
end
```

index:

```
ThinkingSphinx::Index.define :real_teams, :with => :active_record do
    indexes :name
end
```

P.S. I am not that common with rails yet, but as far as I think code's done properly.

Answer (score 0):

Your index definition should refer to `:real_team` (singular, like the model name) instead of `:real_teams`.